# Oracle - How to rollback sequences inside multiple inserts

Tags: oracle, rollback, database-sequence

I have a script (that can fail) with multiple inserts that include nextval as

```
insert into table a (id, value) (id_seq.nextval, 'value');
...
```

If script fails and I rollback the inserts, the sequence isn't rollback and multiple ids won't be in use

Is there a best practice to avoid "losing" ids from sequence on multiple inserts?

I found similar questions but in different context

Comment: Numbers generated by a sequence can not be rolled back, that's by the design. Why do you want to roll it back in the first place?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov I don't want to have gaps between IDs used, there could be hundreds of inserts rollback

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1508205334476

Comment: The **only** job of a generated primary key value is to be unique. It does not matter if that value is `1`, `42`, `-563` or `7890`. Gaps are completely irrelevant. There is nothing you need to do. Don't worry, move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set the current value of an existing sequence. If you need to change the value(currentvalue) of a sequence you have to "increment it back" or recreate it.

"Incrementing back"(dirty workaround):

```
-- current value is 100
ALTER SEQUENCE seq_x  INCREMENT BY -25;--number of wrong increments or max(id)-seq_x.nextval in a procedure
SELECT seq_x.NEXTVAL FROM dual; -increments by 1 step, in this case -25
-- -> new current value is 75
ALTER SEQUENCE seq_x INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Recreate it:

```
DROP SEQUENCE seq_x;
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_x INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 75;-- desired start value
-- You need to reassign privileges, if some were given
```

If you're using a auto increment column instead, you can set it to the highes value in the table by using

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY ID GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH LIMIT VALUE);
-- customize as you need it, i.e. GENERATED BY DEFAULT instead of GENERATED ALWAYS
```

If you always need the last value for whatever reason, you have to select `MAX(id)` from the given table.
But: Missing ids in a table dont hurt performance or anything else, it only hurts some ppl eyes :)

Answer (score 3):

`ROLLBACK` works on `DML`. It removes the effect of any data changes in tables that happened in the current transaction.

`ROLLBACK` can not change the sequence value to its original value (value of the sequence when the transaction is started).

Anyway, `Sequence` is just an incremental number and you will not lose any precious data if it slips by few numbers, until and unless your project needs a continuous sequence and it is the strict requirement. If it is so, then you must find other workarounds.

You can not control the gaps in the sequence.

Cheers!!

Comment: You can check https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1508205334476 for workarounds.

Comment: That must be another question on SO.

Comment: @user7294900 you do not need any "workarounds" - the gaps are not a problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

No way to auto rollback sequence.
And as usual u don't need that.